# Using Microsoft Graph in the simplest way possible to find email

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail

I have an automation project (`.NET Framework`) which currently makes use of `Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices` to easily do simple tasks like finding email in a remote inbox or folder, checking for attachments etc. We grab the data from an organisation email account on: `outlook.office365.com`

Recently I have embarked on rewriting my project in `.NET Core` and this has presented a number of problems including my continued use of `EWS`:

> Today we are sharing our plans to move away from Basic Authentication access for EWS over the next two years, with support ending **Oct. 13, 2020**.
>
> https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/exchange-team-blog/upcoming-changes-to-exchange-web-services-ews-api-for-office-365/ba-p/608055
>
> Microsoft Graph is the recommended API to use for accessing Exchange Online data. New applications designed to access Exchange Online data should use Microsoft Graph.

`EWS` support also seems low within `.NET Core` various warnings appeared in the project after installing.

All my current work with `EWS` is done in a class with a couple of environment variables being passed to setup the `WebCredentials` etc. but as I have read through a number of Microsoft articles (including: [Get access without a user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service)) I have realized nothing will be simple anymore :) on the usage of Graph I have found no straight forward code examples of how to implement this purely back end integration into a mailbox in the simplest possible way.

I'm wondering if someone could give me a simple and appropriate Authentication and authorization example relevant to a back end integration? i.e. one without Administrator consent pop ups or any other pop ups that would not be appropriate to an integration like this, is this still possible?

Comment: Is this helpful? [Setup Graph Managed API](https://github.com/ivfranji/GraphManagedApi/wiki) I wrote that one while transitioning some of my work off from EWS.

Comment: Thanks for the link @IvanFranjic, I am busy looking through everything.

Comment: @IvanFranjic could you please help me understand, in your example we simply set `exchangeServiceContext["user@domain.com"]` at what point would that mailbox's password be provided? Surely registering and authenticating you graph app should not give you god mode into any mailbox on you company azure? Surely you still need to provide passwords for individual mailboxes?

Comment: Once you setup authentication provider as described in github wiki you will get something similar as "Application Impersonation" with Ews and you don't have to provide username / password. That will give you access to scope (mailboxes and grants) which you specified in app settings registration in azure. You still can setup IAuthorizationProvider with different types of authorizations if that one doesn't fit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [net core 2.1 console example](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/blogs/30daysmsgraph-day-15-microsoft-graph-in-dotnet-core-application/)

There are Delegated and Application permissions. Delegated is a popup, and requires a user, application is via a service principal (and can be done non-interactively/in automation).

Step 2 in the above example uses the `User.Read.All` permission. That gets you email address, as well as a bunch of other information about your users. It's way overkill if you just want email. `User.ReadBasic.All` is a much better permission to put on the app registration for your purposes.(The example should work fine with you changing the permissions to `User.ReadBasic.All`)

In the last part of the example (pasted below), you'll want to change the query and most likely want to add an iterator.

```
GraphServiceClient graphClient = GetAuthenticatedGraphClient(config);
List<QueryOption> options = new List<QueryOption>
{
    new QueryOption("$top", "1")
};

var graphResult = graphClient.Users.Request(options).GetAsync().Result;
Console.WriteLine("Graph SDK Result");
Console.WriteLine(graphResult[0].DisplayName);
```

Graph and MSAL may seem complicated at first but are very valuable. Microsoft is adding functionality (and functions) to graph regularly. [Graph 1.0 Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/overview?toc=./ref/toc.json&view=graph-rest-1.0)

Comment: Thanks @ChadCarlton for you input! I will work through your feedback and report back as soon as I can.

Comment: I'd like to add that there are other ways to get this data.. Powershell can also be used easily.